# How to save datagridview to database using linq

Tags: c#, database, winforms, linq, datagridview

Hello I wonder how to save rows in a datagridview to a database with linq.
My datagridview contains two columns: CustomerID and Customer. Also my database contains these two columns: CustomerID and Customer.

```
        private void saveToolStripButton_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                Customer.EndEdit();
                kundhandler.customername();
                kundhandler.SubmitChanges();
                MessageBox.Show("Customer save");
        }

        public void CustomerName()
        {
            db.CustomerName();
        }
        public void SubmitChanges()
        {
            db.SubmitChanges();
        }


        DataContext db = new DataContext();
        public void CustomerName()
        {
            var qry = from i in db.Customer
                      select i;
             db.SubmitChanges();
        }

        public void SubmitChanges()
        {
            db.SubmitChanges();

        }
```

Comment: Check if this helps you http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/kannagoud/insertupdatedelete-in-datagridview-using-linq-in-windows-forms/

Answer (score 0):

try something like this, but you will need to loop through the DataTable and perform the InsertOnSubmit for each row in the gridview. then call SubmitChanges once at the end.

you can find more information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386941.aspx) :

```
DBTableRow dbrow= new DBTableRow 
{
   CustomerID= 12000,
   Customer= "John Smith"
};

// Add the new object to the Customer collection.
db.DBTableRow.InsertOnSubmit(dbrow);

 // Submit the change to the database.
 try
 {
    db.SubmitChanges();
 }
 catch (Exception e)
{
    // perform some exception handling
}
```

Comment: I understand the code you wrote. But i dont get the first how to apply this on my datagridview.

Comment: you can extract data from a database using LINQ select - this will return an IEnumerable list which you can bind to the datagrid.